# Moving an MKMapView to a specific location relative to the superview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, mkmapview

I have a few annotations added to a MKMapView, and when the user clicks on one of the annotations, it displays a UICalloutView with a right accessory button which adds a UIView to the map, displaying some information about that specific location. This UIView is centred in the superview of the map, and in order to show that the information in that view is relative to the annotation, I would like to shift the visible map rect down (on the y axis), and center it on the x axis so that the annotation is directly under the view.

I am doing the following to centre the annotation, however, I don't know how to move the annotation down on the y axis so that it sits under the added UIView. Please can you tell me how I can do so?

```
[self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:[annotation coordinate] animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the size of the information view, then you know how much you want to use the map (based on the difference between its size and the map view size). Now you know the offset, you can calculate the point (in the view coordinate system) that should be moved to the centre so that the annotation is moved down). Then you can use `convertPoint:toCoordinateFromView:` to find the coordinate for that point to use with `setCenterCoordinate:animated:`.

Comment: Thanks, working fine on the x coord with the point's x being `self.view.center`. However, please can you clarify for the y coord?

Comment: Your aim is to move the map content down, so the annotation is below the info view. You need to know how far to move it. Then work out what the center geo coord of the map needs to be. You're currently moving the annotation to the center but that isn't what you describe you need.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to shift the map down so it's centered on a particular `coordinate`, but shift it down, say, 40%, so you have space for something above it, you could do something like the following:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D center = coordinate;
center.latitude -= self.mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta * 0.40;
[self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:center animated:YES];
```